# Cython's cdef function use of temporary array, does it needs to be remove/deallocated?

Tags: cython

I've seen a cython code with cdef function that uses a temporary array

```
cdef void some_funct (int* OUT, int size, int const_val) nogil:
    cdef:
        int blah.. blah...blah... 
        float    out_tmp[8]
  
    for i in range(64):
        .....
        ..... out_tmp is involved somehow as intermediate array
```

What is out_tmp ? Is it a vector? a C++ array? a pointer? Do I need to remove/delete or deallocate it before exiting cdef function or cython will do that automatically? If need to manually clean, how to remove/delete/deallocate?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the array stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696024/how-is-the-array-stored-in-memory)

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258724/5769463

Comment: I'm not completely convinced it's a duplicate (having answered the question I do have a vested interest now though...). Those links are about C and I don't think it's necessarily obvious what C structure Cython is creating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out_tmp` is a stack-allocated C array. It exists only for the duration of the function call (so don't return a pointer to it!) and does not need deallocating.